# How to exclude specific HTTP method from `javax.servlet.Filter`?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, servlet-filters, http-method

I would like to exclude HTTP `OPTION` requests from my `javax.servlet.Filter`. How can I achieve it?

Filter registration:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {

    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registrationBean.setFilter(authorizationRequestFilter());
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/persons/*", "/accounts/*");

    return registrationBean;
}
```

I would like to avoid XML configuration.

**Actual state**

Now I am excluding `OPTIONS` method in filter:

```
 @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

        if ("OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        } else {
            String accessToken = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN);
            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(accessToken)) {
                HttpResponseWriter.throwUnauthorized(res);
            } else {
                AccountLoginData account = loginService.find(accessToken);
                if (account == null) {
                    HttpResponseWriter.throwForbidden(res);
                } else {
                    chain.doFilter(req, res);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: This already can't be acheived by XML configuration in first place and thus programmatic configuration can do very little. This can only be achieved by editing filter's `doFilter()` implementation.

Comment: @BalusC - I added my code, but I would like to avoid do it manually.

Comment: You don't need to show filter code for that, it only adds distracting noise to question. I understand that, but you can't avoid doing that manually. Unless Spring Boot (which I'm totally not familiar with) has some reflection/AOP trickery under its covers in this regard, but I wouldn't expect that.

Comment: I see, thanks for clarification. I thought there will be an options to avoid doing it manually.

Comment: It already can't be achieved by XML configuration in first place. It if were, programmatic configuration would be a breeze.